# Validated by Class(Constraint class) for Custom Annotation not getting invoked

Tags: java, spring, validation, annotations

I have recently started working on custom Annotations. I created a sample spring boot project where it works fine, but When I try to integrate with my project code, the validation class is not getting invoked.

ValidateField.java

```
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;


@Documented
@Target(value = { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Constraint(validatedBy = { RequestDataValidator.class })
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidateField {

    String message() default "invalid or value not present";

    int revision() default 1;

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

RequestDataValidator.java

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class RequestDataValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidateField, String>{

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidateField constraintAnnotation) {
        System.out.println("in Initialize method");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        System.out.println("in Initialize method");
            return (value != null && !value.isEmpty());
    }

}
```

The controller class is as follows.
Please note that the @Valid annotation is used with @RequestBody

```
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;


@Api
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/service")
public interface UIController {

    @POST
    @Path("/getRules")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @ApiOperation(
            value = "Respond Hello <name>!",
            response = Response.class
    )
    @ApiResponses(
            value = {
                    @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Service not available"),
                    @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Unexpected Runtime error")
                    })
    public Response getRules(@Valid@RequestBody SampleRequest discountPromoDetailsRequest);

}
```

I have checked if the annotation gets applied to the field. Turns out it does. I checked it by using

```
field.getDeclaredAnnotations()
```

SampleRequest.java

```
public class SampleRequest {

    private String name;

    @ValidateField
    private String lastName;

    private Long phNum;

    private String address;
    .
    .
    //getters and setters of the same.

}
```

I am now not sure what can be the cause for the RequestDataValidator not getting called.

I am working on this from last 3 days and I still don't have it working in the project.

Any Help is highly appreciated.